# dfl_debug.lib not found

Tags: d, dmd, tango

I'm trying to compile my first application using Forms in D, using the DFL / Tango libraries, but the compiler first attempt said: `DFL lib files not found`.

Then I tried to compile the libs, and got the following error:

```
not found: \dmd\import\import\*.obj 
dfl_debug.lib not found
```

I'm using the `DMD compiler`, version `v2.055`.

How I fix it?

Comment: I don't think you can use Tango with D2 (yet).

Comment: It's being ported ( https://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2 ), but no, if you're using any released versions of Tango, you can't use D2. I don't know if DFL has been ported to D2 or not, but if it's using Tango (as opposed to you using Tango in conjunction with it), then probably not.

Comment: Rayerd's [DFL fork](https://github.com/Rayerd/dfl) is compatible with 2.057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is download the latest [snapshot](http://wiki.dprogramming.com/Dfl/Snapshots) archive, extract this into where dmd is installed. Then get the latest source from [github/Rayerd](https://github.com/Rayerd/dfl) and copy the win32/dfl directory over the dfl directory from the archive. And finally I use the dfl.exe executable to compile my program.

Rayerd hasn't been keeping up, so check out pull requests and possible other repos to get a working build.

Comment: Did you do it actually or it's just a suggestion?

Comment: @menjaraz, That is what I have done to get it compiling with D2. And I've done it quite recently too.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Its what I expected but the use of present tense confused me a bit. Good news.

Comment: +1: Rayerd's DFL fork works well now on my box: DMD 2.059 - Windows 7.